# angular Create element based on scope attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can i control a directive's template based on a $scope variable that has already been evaluated (compiled?) by angular?

For example this won't work since $scope

```
app.directive('inputType', function(){
    var template;

    if ($scope.inputType === 'input') {
         template = "<input ng-attr-my-attribute='" + $scope.myAttribute + "' />";
    }

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            inputType: '=',
            myAttribute: '='
        },
        template: template
    }    
})

<inputType inputType="input" my-attribute="some value"></inputType>
```

In this example i want the element type (input, textarea, checkbox, etc) to be controlled by a dynamic `$scope` property.

Comment: defining `template` variable in HTML should work for you. Something like,
`<inputType template="variable">

Comment: the challenge is getting the html from its own scope

Answer (score 1):

You would do all the conditional markup in the template and you can base that logic on a two-way bound scope variable from a parent controller for example. Also you have not used you directive correctly in the HTML. You need to define the directive in camel case an use snake case in your markup. Try this

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/GDlfSeIv374VMijCAlrx)

**index.html**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <input-type-dir  input-type="inputs.one"></input-type-dir>
    <input-type-dir  input-type="inputs.two"></input-type-dir>
    <input-type-dir  input-type="inputs.three"></input-type-dir>
</body>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.inputs = {
        one    : 'text',
        two    : 'checkbox',
        three  : 'textarea'
    };

});

app.directive('inputTypeDir', function(){

    return {

        restrict: 'E',

        scope: {
            inputType: '='
        },

        templateUrl: 'template.html'

    }

});
```

**template.html**

```
<input ng-if="inputType !== 'textarea'" type="{{inputType}}">
<textarea ng-if="inputType === 'textarea'" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Alternatively, you could just access the attributes in the link function if you don't want to create an isolate scope and if you only needed to pass in string values:

**index**

```
<input-type-dir  foo="text"></input-type-dir>
<input-type-dir  foo="checkbox"></input-type-dir>
<input-type-dir  foo="textarea"></input-type-dir>
```

**directive def**

```
link: function(scope, el, attrs){ 
    scope.foo = attrs.foo;
}
```

**tempalte**

```
<input ng-if="foo !== 'textarea'" type="{{foo}}">
```